# force required to do damage to child's leg/feet in collision

Tags: human-biology, bio-mechanics

I'm currently working on a toy robot for a student project. Part of this robot is the fact that it will be moving around quite fast. As such hitting the child can and most likely will happen. As such we are obviously worried about safety. So what type of forces can a child safely withstand? The robot will most likely not be very tall (45 cm) and be shaped like the top half of a sphere, as such most collisions will happen with the shins or the feet.

I do hope this is in the correct  stack exchange and that this isn't supposed to go into a different stack exchange.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not in the scope of biology SE, not likely to be answerable given the current information, not likely to be answerable at all (I doubt any one has been able to get funding to study how much force a child's legs can take before they break...) & there's too many variables. You should be considering other options first such as how to make the robot not damage a child, like padding, shape, or not having it hit the child at all!

Comment: You should also take in account that it is a toy. Even if a collision does not damage the child, it might still scare it. Which is reason enough to avoid collisions.

Comment: I know that I have to use padding but the main question is: how much padding? In order to find out I would like to know a maximum safe force so that I can calculate how much padding to add. I will of course add in AI that avoids targets but this can never be assumed to work(it only has to go wrong once).